# "möchten" im Sinne von "sollen"

Tags: verb, verb-usage, modal-verb

Es scheint mir, als ob ich das Verb "möchten" im Sinne von "sollen" gehört habe.
Kann das sein oder habe ich mich verhört?

1. Sag bitte Claus, er möchte (bitte?) zu mir kommen.
2. Sag bitte Claus, er soll zu mir kommen.

Hat das etwas mit dem "mögen" zu tun?

3. Sag bitte Claus, er möge (bitte?) zu mir kommen.

Comment: Das Verb *mögen* kann in der Tat im Sinne von *sollen* verwendet werden. *Er/sie/es möge/möchte* ist der Konjunktiv I/II.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Sollen' hat neben der modalen Bedeutung einer *Verpflichtung* oder *Anordnung*:

> Ich soll morgen schon um 7 im Büro sein.

die daraus abgeleitete Bedeutung *jemand anderes wünscht, dass ... / jemand anderes fordert dich auf, zu ...*:

> Du sollst sofort nach Hause kommen.

Solche übermittelten Aufforderungen können auch mit Einleitesatz überbracht werden:

> Deine Frau hat gesagt, du sollst sofort nach Hause kommen.

Wie Janka schrieb, kann das auch mit *mögen* ausgedrückt werden. Dann ist die Aufforderung weniger nachdrücklich und in die Form eines Wunsches gekleidet. Da jedoch im Satz

> Deine Frau hat gesagt, du mögest sofort nach Hause kommen

der Konjunktiv 1 sehr gehoben bzw. veraltet ist, weicht man üblicherweise auf den Konjunktiv 2 aus:

> Deine Frau hat gesagt, du möchtest (doch bitte) sofort nach Hause kommen.

Nach Resolutheit und Nachdrücklichkeit geordnet hat man im Deutschen beim Auffordern u.a. folgende Möglichkeiten:

> *Imperativ + gefälligst*: Räum gefälligst dein Zimmer auf.
>
> *Imperativ*: Lass den Quatsch.
>
> *müssen*: Sie müssen hier warten, bis Sie aufgerufen werden.
>
> *sollen*: Ihr sollt doch noch nicht den Fußboden in der Küche betreten, der ist doch frisch verlegt!
>
> *mögen (Konjunktiv)*: Sie möchten bitte hier warten.
>
> *Imperativ + bitte*: Gib mir bitte den Stift zurück.

Und als Wünsche:

> *Imperativ + 'doch mal'*: Hilf mir doch mal bei der Matheaufgabe.
>
> *Frage mit können (Indikativ)*: Kannst du mir morgen dein Auto leihen?
>
> *Frage mit können (Konjunktiv 2)*: Könntest du mir mal kurz helfen?

Die Ordnung dieser Liste ist nicht strikt zu verstehen und ist auch weit von jeder Vollständigkeit entfernt. Mit der Frage ist jedoch die Graduierung der Nachdrücklichkeit bei Aufforderungen angesprochen. Dafür gibt es eine Fülle sprachlicher Möglichkeiten: die Modi Imperativ und Konjunktiv, Frage-Wortstellung, Wunschsatz-Wortstellung, Infinitiv ('*Hinlegen!*') und Partizip 2 ('*Hiergeblieben*!'), Modalverben im Indikativ und Konjunktiv, Einsatz von Modalpartikeln und modalisierenden Adverbien, 'performative Verben' ('*hiermit fordere ich Sie auf, den ausstehenden Betrag innerhalb einer Woche zu zahlen*'), verkürzte Sätze ('*Tür zu!'*) und vieles andere mehr. Diese Elemente können vielfältig miteinander kombiniert werden, um verschiedene Stufen von Freundlichkeit, Höflichkeit und Striktheit der Erwartung auf einer Skala von aggressivem Befehlen bis zu sanftestem Bitten auszudrücken, von denen in der Liste nur ein sehr kleiner Teil wiedergegeben ist.

Comment: Deine Beispiele sind alle gut und schön, nur fehlt die Erklärung, dass der Konjunktiv in den Beispieen der Frage hauptsächlich durch die indirekte Rede bedingt ist und mit irgendeiner Art, den Imperativ auszudrücken, erst mal nicht viel zu tun hat.

Comment: @tofro: Stimmt, teilweise, allerdings wird heute im gesprochenen Deutsch die indirekte Rede wenn es irgend geht mit dem Indikativ angeschlossen: _Er hat gesagt, er kommt um 12._ Das heißt, man hat da jetzt eine Auswahlmöglichkeit. Wenn man dort den Konjunktiv wählt, ist man je nachdem in der geschriebenen Sprache in einem förmlichen oder offiziellen Register oder in einem distanzierenden Modus: _Er sagte, er komme (= sehr gehoben) / Er hat gesagt, er käme um 12._ So oder so, es geht in den Bsp.n um die Übermittlung einer Aufforderung, das geht auch mit Indikativ, siehe 2. Beispiel [weiter...]

Comment: [... weiter] @tofro: Das Modalverb _mögen_ ist in mancher Hinsicht ein Sonderfall, u.a. auch, weil es wie in 1. im Konj. unmarkiert zur Übermittlung einer Aufforderung dienen kann. Vgl.: _Sag ihm bitte, er solle kommen_ (zu hochsprachlich) / _Sag ihm bitte, er sollte kommen_ (Konj. 2 wird als Präteritum verstanden und der Satz damit unsinnig; ähnlich mit _müsse_, _müsste_ ginge aber). Anders als mit _sollen_ geht hier mit _mögen_ der Indikativ nicht: _*Sag ihm bitte, er mag kommen._ (= falsch). Man könnte also auch sagen, der Konj. wurde nur deshalb gewählt, weil der Indikativ nicht geht.

Comment: Hmm. "...wird, wenn es irgend geht, mit Indikativ..." das ist sehr generell, und falsch. Umgangssprachlich ja, in geschriebener Sprache scheint man sich allerdings noch ein bißchen mehr anzustrengen. Ich finde es nicht richtig, **Lernern** der Sprache das so nahezulegen. Wenn jemand eine C-Sprachprüfung ablegt, *muss* er das richtig können.

Comment: @tofro: Es ist falsch, (aber) umgangssprachlich ja - ?? Wenn jemand in einer mündlichen C-Sprachprüfung die Anschlüsse einer indirekten Rede so macht wie im gesprochenen Deutschen üblich, wird er deswegen keine Probleme bekommen. In einem Deutschkurs sehe ich keine Notwendigkeit, die aktive Beherrschung des Konj. 1 in indirekter Rede zu vermitteln; für formelle Briefe wird da der Konj. 2 genügen, der aber bei Modalverben spezielle Funktionen hat. Diese sollten schon auf A2-B1-Level beherrscht werden, auch aktiv. Für die Weitergabe von Aufforderungen gelten spezielle Regeln, die sind hier Thema